# Cannot find android mode in Processing

Tags: java, android, windows, deployment, ant

As the title describes, i cannot find the Android mode(in order to install) in [Processing](https://processing.org/download/). I can only find Java mode and JavaScript mode(which i installed).

I am using Windows 7 64 bit.

Note that i have installed Java jdk, added the relevant path to environment variables Path, and installed android SDK Tools, android sdk platform tools, the latest android sdk build tools and from android 4.1.2(API 16) to Android 5.0.1(API 21).

I read about manually installing android mode but all download links i found are not working. I am also wondering if i need to add any more environment variables, such as in a [guide](http://forum.processing.org/one/topic/android-problems.html) i found in Processing website. Here is the relevant part:

> If you're on Windows, then you might need to mess with the System PATH
>   variables. You can edit the PATH variables by right-clicking on
>   Computer > Properties > Change Properties > Advanced > Environment
>   Variables . WARNING : Messing with these variables can seriously mess
>   up your computer if not done properly. You should check the following:
>
> Variable JAVA_HOME should point to the location of the bin folder
>   within the JDK. Variable ANDROID_HOME should point to the location of
>   the bin folder within the Android folder. Variable ANT_HOME should
>   point to the location of the ant folder within the android tools
>   folder. Variable ADB_HOME should point to the location of the location
>   of the android/android-sdk/platform-tools folder. All of these
>   variables should be referenced from within the PATH variable. You can
>   reference a variable by specifying its name surrounded by percent
>   signs ( % ). In order for the variable to be properly unwrapped, it
>   must be enclosed in percent signs and each individual variable must be
>   separated by a semicolon. For example:
>   "%JAVA_HOME%;%ANT_HOME%;ADB_HOME%;%ANDROID_HOME%"

Also, i found that android.sdk.path was missing from the preferences folder of Processing.

Finally, do i need ant?

EDIT:
I have also downloaded the android mode manually from [here](http://www.blurrypaths.com/post/52573899794/processing-2-0-modes-download-links), unzipped and copied in the below location:
C:\Users\\Documents\Processing\modes\

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to install pre-release 3.0a5.
Latest stable release 2.2.1 does not have an android mode.